# express server shutting down if there is a pg error

Tags: javascript, express, node-postgres

I have an express app attached to a pg database. I am working on handling errors. I would like the pg error messages to be sent to the frontend so the user knows why this form did not send. Right now if I send in information to this endpoint that is against my database constraints it shuts down my server.

I think this has to do with how I am handling errors but I am new to express and a bit confused on how to go about this.

Here is my code:
express route:

```
app.post('/api/inbox', inbox.createInbox)
```

createInbox function:

```
 const createInbox = (request, response) => {
    const { name, email, body, tag, subject } = request.body
      console.log("request body", request.body)
        pool.query('INSERT INTO inbox (name, email, body, tag, subject ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)', [name, email, body, tag, subject ], (error, results) => {
          if (error) {
            return console.error(err.message);
          }
          console.log("get to Success  contact")
          response.status(200).send(`Inbox Added`)
        })
       
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried sending an error message to the user before returning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, your server was probably shutting down because you were referencing `err.message` in `console.error(err.message)`, but the variable name is `error`, not `err`.

You also need to send an error response back to the client.  Every http request your server receives needs to send some type of response:

```
const createInbox = (request, response) => {
    const { name, email, body, tag, subject } = request.body
      console.log("request body", request.body)
        pool.query('INSERT INTO inbox (name, email, body, tag, subject ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)', [name, email, body, tag, subject ], (error, results) => {
          if (error) {
            console.error(error.message);                // log correct variable
            response.status(500).send(error.message);    // send error response
            return;
          }
          console.log("get to Success  contact")
          response.status(200).send(`Inbox Added`)
        })
       
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server is shutting down because your callback function is referencing `error` and not `err`.

Try the code below:

```
 const createInbox = (request, response) => {
        const { name, email, body, tag, subject } = request.body
          console.log("request body", request.body)
            pool.query('INSERT INTO inbox (name, email, body, tag, subject ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)', [name, email, body, tag, subject ], (err, results) => {
              if (err) {
                return console.error(err.message);
              } else
              console.log("get to Success contact")
              response.status(200).send(`Inbox Added`)
            })
           
      }
```